# Select elements with class except one with specific id

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

```
$('.ui-widget-content').css('border','none');
    $('#helpDialog .ui-widget-content').addClass('HelpDialogBorder');
```

I am doing like this to remove border. But, there is an element where I want to keep border.

Is there any way in first line itself to select all elements with class "ui-widget-content" but except one with id "helpDialog"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('.ui-widget-content:not(#helpDialog)').css('border', 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpSer/)):

```
$('.ui-widget-content').not('#helpDialog').css('border','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `$('.ui-widget-content').not('#id')`