# jquery - selector type minus name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select elements with class except one with specific id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636275/select-elements-with-class-except-one-with-specific-id)

I have to select type select of a form but I want to discard the ID with a name Like a word.

I have:

```
 $("select").onchange(function(){
   alert("change");
 });
```

I'd like type of

```
$("select minus select with ID like 'noChange'").onchange(function(){
   alert("change");
 });
```

Tnx tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector):

```
$("select:not(#noChange)").onchange(function(){
   alert("change");
});
```

Or, if `noChange` is part of the ID and not the exact ID:

```
$("select:not([id*='noChange'])").onchange(function(){
   alert("change");
});
```

Comment: sorry and if I Want with like? function `formToJsonByIdLike(nameForm,like)
{
 var jsonForm={};
 $("input,select,checkbox:[id*="+like+"]", $(nameForm)).each(function(index){
   jsonForm[$(this).attr("id")] = this.value;
 });
 return jsonForm;
}`